# Can a rank 1 tensor represent the same information that a rank n tensor does?

Tags: tensors, tensor-rank

So, I was studying quantum mechanics, and a question came up. In quantum mechanics, we work in a Hilbert space, and the basis that we choose can represent all the information that we can have in order to describe a system. When we need more information to describe the problem we just increase the dimension of our space. So for a given basis, we can represent a vector in this space as a column matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}
  \alpha_{1} \\
  \alpha_{2} \\
  \vdots \\
  \alpha_{m} \\
\end{bmatrix}$
that is a rank 1 tensor. In this case, it seems that I just have to increase the number of the ordered values $\alpha$ in order to describe a more complex problem in QM. But there is others problems in physics, like deformations, that we use rank 2 tensor, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor). So there as problems that even if their get more complicated I can only increase the dimension of a rank 1 tensor, but there are other problems that seem to not be enough just increase the dimension of a rank 1 tensor. So because when I increase the rank of a tensor, I have more structure, and then I can represent more information. So my question is: **What is the difference in the information that a rank 2 tensor can hold that a rank 1 tensor can't? Can I represent the information of a rank 2 tensor with rank 1 tensors? Can I extend this idea to a rank n tensor ?**

By way of example, can a column matrix with 4 values describe the same problem as a 2x2 matrix ?

Comment: I've never really understood what it is that physicists are talking about when they talk about tensors, but if I understand you correctly, then a "rank 2 tensor" is for you just a matrix $A,$ or a linear transformation $A:V\to W,$ in which case it is a vector (i.e. a "rank 1 tensor") in the vector space $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W).$ More generally any tensor is an element of some vector space, hence is a "rank 1 tensor."

Comment: The best way to understand why in physics a second order tensor is not just a vector in block form is to realize that physics is very often interested in tensor *fields* i.e. tensor valued functions on manifolds and how they transform under coordinate changes. Sean Carroll's book *Spacetime and Geometry* explains this well. The habit to call a tensor *field* a tensor confuses many people. If they were just higher order matrices then of course we could store the information however we want.